# django - I can't use the Q filter model with 2 related databases

Tags: python, sql, django, database, model

I have the 2 following models related with 2 different databases at models.py:

```
class AnalogicalValues(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    description = models.ForeignKey(ExpensesDescription, models.DO_NOTHING)
    continent_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'WorldContinent', db_column='continent_id', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )
    (...)hide code(...)
    city_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'WorldCity', db_column='city_id', verbose_name='City', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )
    value = models.FloatField()
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='user_id', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'analogical_values'
        ordering = ('-date', '-id')


class WorldCity(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='City')
    continent = models.ForeignKey(WorldContinent, models.DO_NOTHING)
    country = models.ForeignKey(WorldCountry, models.DO_NOTHING)
    subcountry = models.ForeignKey(WorldSubcountry, models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_update_db = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cities'
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name_plural = 'List of World Cities'
        verbose_name = 'World City'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The relationship between them are city_id from AnalogicalValues and id from WorldCity and each model is mapped of respective database at routers.py. The description field on AnalogicalValues is a foreignkey of other table in same database as analogical_values and it's working fine.

```
class WorldRouter:

    route_app_labels = {'myapp'}
    route_model_list = {'WorldCity'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if (
            model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels and 
            model._meta.object_name in self.route_model_list
        ):
            return 'world_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if (
            model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels and 
            model._meta.object_name in self.route_model_list
        ):
            return 'world_db'
        return None
    
    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

class ExpensesRouter:
    route_app_labels = {'myapp'}
    route_model_list = {'AnalogicalValues'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if (
            model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels and 
            model._meta.object_name in self.route_model_list
        ):
            return 'expenses_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if (
            model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels and 
            model._meta.object_name in self.route_model_list
        ):
            return 'expenses_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None
```

In models.py I want to get all results of all columns regarding the string that I write on 'filterData' form:

```
from . import models
from django.views import generic

class DataView(generic.ListView, generic.FormView):

    (...some code...)

    model = models.AnalogicalValues
    paginate_by = 10

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        (...some code...)

        datalist = self.model.objects.filter(
                    Q(user_id__exact=self.request.user) &
                    (
                        Q(date__icontains=kwargs['filterData'])
                        | Q(description__name__icontains=kwargs['filterData'])
                        | Q(city_id__name__icontains=kwargs['filterData'])
                        | Q(value__icontains=kwargs['filterData'])
                        | Q(comments__icontains=kwargs['filterData'])
                    )
                )
        self.paginate_by = datalist.count()

        (...some code...)

        return render(self.request, self.template_name, {
        'datalist': datalist,
        (...some args...)

    })
```

When django reaches the self.paginate_by line, I get this error

```
Environment:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

The above exception ((1146, "Table 'EXPENSES.cities' doesn't exist")) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/BN_APP/myapp/views.py", line 43, in dispatch
    return super(UserAccessMixin, self).dispatch(self.request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 85, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/BN_APP/myapp/views.py", line 1256, in post
    return FinancialDataView.get(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/BN_APP/myapp/views.py", line 1158, in get
    self.paginate_by = datalist.count()
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 411, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 515, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 500, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/bruno/Python/BN_APP/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /financial_data/
Exception Value: (1146, "Table 'EXPENSES.cities' doesn't exist")
```

I did some digging and I check that the query that it's built misses the database name for table cities. Can anyone help me out with it please? Thank you

---

(Edited)

Query that is performed:

```
USE EXPENSES;
SELECT
    analogical_values.id
  , analogical_values.date
  , analogical_values.description_id
  , analogical_values.transaction_type_id
  , analogical_values.payment_method_id
  , analogical_values.continent_id
  , analogical_values.country_id
  , analogical_values.subcountry_id
  , analogical_values.city_id
  , analogical_values.value
  , analogical_values.comments
  , analogical_values.user_id
  , analogical_values.last_update_db 

FROM
    analogical_values
    INNER JOIN
        description
        ON
            (
                analogical_values. description_id = description.description_id
            )
    INNER JOIN
        transaction_type
        ON
            (
                analogical_values.transaction_type_id = transaction_type.transaction_type_id
            )
    INNER JOIN
        payment_method
        ON
            (
                analogical_values.payment_method_id = payment_method.payment_method_id
            )
    INNER JOIN
        countries 
        ON
            (
                analogical_values.country_id = countries.id
            )
    INNER JOIN
        cities
        ON
            (
                analogical_values.city_id = cities.id
            )
WHERE
    (
        analogical_values.user_id = 2
        AND
        (
            analogical_values.date LIKE '%test%'
            OR description.name LIKE '%test%'
                OR transaction_type.name LIKE '%test%'
                OR payment_method.name LIKE '%test%'
            OR countries.name LIKE '%test%'
                OR cities.name LIKE '%test%' 
                OR analogical_values.value LIKE '%test%'
            OR analogical_values.comments LIKE '%test%'
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    analogical_values.date DESC, analogical_values.id DESC
```

In the last 2 INNER JOINS, the tables belongs to WORLD database, e.g., WORLD.countries and WORLD.cities

Comment: Which DB are you using and are these databases in different instances or in the same instance? You can't perform queries that span separate DBs. Can you share your DATABASES setting?

Comment: I just edit the post and I added the query (see at the bottom)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what do you mean by same instance? It is a mariaDB server and the 2 databases (EXPENSES and WORLD) are in the same server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it's not the best practice, but I did a filter directly from the model and grab all ids for the Q filter and it worked

```
if kwargs['filterData']:
    city_list = models.WorldCity.objects.filter(name__icontains=kwargs['filterData']).values()
    city_id = []
    [city_id.append(cur_city.get('id')) for cur_city in city_list]
else:
    city_id = models.WorldCity.objects.none()

datalist = self.model.objects.filter(
    Q(user_id__exact=self.request.user) &
    (
        Q(date__icontains=kwargs['filterData'])
        | Q(description__name__icontains=kwargs['filterData'])
        | Q(city_id__id__in=city_id)
        | Q(value__icontains=kwargs['filterData'])
        | Q(comments__icontains=kwargs['filterData'])
    )
)

    self.paginate_by = datalist.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception Value: (1146, "Table 'EXPENSES.cities' doesn't exist")
```

if you read your exception it is easy to see that table does not exists.
Probably make migrations first.

Comment: The table exists, but in other database. I think the problem is in the relationship configuration. For instance, if a write datalist = self.model.objects.all() I can get the correct value of city_id. This error occurs when I try to make a filter with Q model, where I have fields in expenses_db.analogical_values table and world_db.cities table